I don't know why I'm receiving "Exception has occurred" in this situation
I'm trying to run code from https://github.com/DDI-Dataset/DDI-Code with its dataset (already downloaded and added to a folder, as instructed by the author), and I get the message "Exception has occurred: Exception Please visit https://stanfordaimi.azurewebsites.net/datasets/35866158-8196-48d8-87bf-50dca81df965 to download the DDI dataset." while using the python debugger in VScode.
Below is the code from the file ddi_dataset.py.
"""Code for loading DDI Dataset."""

from torch.utils.data import Subset
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision import transforms as T
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

means = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
stds  = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
test_transform = T.Compose([
    lambda x: x.convert('RGB'),
    T.Resize(299),
    T.CenterCrop(299),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize(mean=means, std=stds)
])

class DDI_Dataset(ImageFolder):
    _DDI_download_link = "https://stanfordaimi.azurewebsites.net/datasets/35866158-8196-48d8-87bf-50dca81df965"
    """DDI Dataset.

    Args:
        root     (str): Root directory of dataset.
        csv_path (str): Path to the metadata CSV file. Defaults to `{root}/ddi_metadata.csv`
        transform     : Function to transform and collate image input. (can use test_transform from this file) 
    """ 
   # root = 'C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\desktop\\CSproject\\datasets\\DDI\\images'
    def __init__(self, root, csv_path=None, download=True, transform=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if csv_path is None:
            csv_path = os.path.join(root, "ddi_metadata.csv")
        if not os.path.exists(csv_path) and download:
            raise Exception(f"Please visit <{DDI_Dataset._DDI_download_link}> to download the DDI dataset.")
        assert os.path.exists(csv_path), f"Path not found <{csv_path}>."
        super(DDI_Dataset, self).__init__(root, *args, transform=transform, **kwargs)
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        m_key = 'malignant'
        if m_key not in self.annotations:
            self.annotations[m_key] = self.annotations['malignancy(malig=1)'].apply(lambda x: x==1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img, target = super(DDI_Dataset, self).__getitem__(index)
        path = self.imgs[index][0]        
        annotation = dict(self.annotations[self.annotations.DDI_file==path.split("/")[-1]])
        target = int(annotation['malignant'].item()) # 1 if malignant, 0 if benign
        skin_tone = annotation['skin_tone'].item() # Fitzpatrick- 12, 34, or 56
        return path, img, target, skin_tone

    """Return a subset of the DDI dataset based on skin tones and malignancy of lesion.

    Args:
        skin_tone    (list of int): Which skin tones to include in the subset. Options are {12, 34, 56}.
        diagnosis    (list of str): Include malignant and/or benign images. Options are {"benign", "malignant"}
    """
    def subset(self, skin_tone=None, diagnosis=None):
        skin_tone = [12, 34, 56] if skin_tone is None else skin_tone
        diagnosis = ["benign", "malignant"] if diagnosis is None else diagnosis
        for si in skin_tone: 
            assert si in [12,34,56], f"{si} is not a valid skin tone"
        for di in diagnosis: 
            assert di in ["benign", "malignant"], f"{di} is not a valid diagnosis"
        indices = np.where(self.annotations['skin_tone'].isin(skin_tone) & \
                           self.annotations['malignant'].isin([di=="malignant" for di in diagnosis]))[0]
        return Subset(self, indices)

I thought that the problem is that the variable root does not include any file path so I tried to add an absolute file path to it (the comment above, root = 'C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\desktop\\CSproject\\datasets\\DDI\\images'); however, the same error message came out.
Below is the file's location in my computer.
ddi_dataset.py: C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\ddi_dataset.py
Images:
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\images
('images' is the folder where I put the PNG:s and ddi_metadata.csv)
Additionally, below is the code from eval_ddi.py where it calls the DDI_Dataset
"""
Code to evaluate the models trained for our paper, 
    "Disparities in Dermatology AI Performance on a Diverse, 
     Curated Clinical Image Set",
on the DDI dataset. 

Note: assumes DDI data is organized as
    ./DDI
        /images
            /000001.png
            /000002.png
            ...
        /ddi_metadata.csv

(After downloading from the Stanford AIMI repository, this requires moving all .png files into a new subdirectory titled "images".)

------------------------------------------------------
Examples:

(1) w/command line interface
# evaluate DeepDerm on DDI and store results in `DDI-results`
>>>python3 eval_ddi.py --model=DeepDerm --data_dir=DDI --eval_dir=DDI-results 

(2) w/python functions
>>>import eval_ddi
>>>import ddi_model
>>>model = ddi_model.load_model("DeepDerm") # load DeepDerm model
>>>eval_results = eval_ddi.eval_model(model, "DDI") # evaluate images in DDI folder
"""

import argparse
from ddi_dataset import DDI_Dataset, test_transform
from ddi_model import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.metrics import (f1_score, balanced_accuracy_score, 
    classification_report, confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc)
import torch
import tqdm


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default="DDI-models", 
        help="File path for where to save models.")
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default="DeepDerm", 
        help="Name of the model to load (HAM10000, DeepDerm, GroupDRO, CORAL,"\
             " or CDANN).")
    parser.add_argument('--no_download', action='store_true', default=False,
        help="Set to disable downloading models.")
    parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default="DDI", 
        help="Folder containing dataset to load. Structure should be: (1) `[data_dir]/images` contains all images; (2) `[data_dir]/ddi_metadata.csv` contains the CSV metadata for the DDI dataset")
    parser.add_argument('--eval_dir', type=str, default="DDI-results", 
        help="Folder to store evaluation results.")
    parser.add_argument('--use_gpu', action='store_true', default=False,
        help="Set to use GPU for evaluation.")
    parser.add_argument('--plot', action='store_true', default=False,
        help="Set to show ROC plot.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def eval_model(model, dataset, use_gpu=False, show_plot=False):
    """Evaluate loaded model on provided image dataset. Assumes supplied image 
    directory corresponds to `root` input for torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder
    class. Assumes the data is split into binary/malignant labels, as this is 
    what our models are trained+evaluated on."""

    use_gpu = (use_gpu and torch.cuda.is_available())
    device = torch.device("cuda") if use_gpu else torch.device("cpu")

    # load dataset
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                    dataset,
                    batch_size=32, shuffle=False,
                    num_workers=0, pin_memory=use_gpu)

    # prepare model for evaluation
    model.to(device).eval()

    # log output for all images in dataset
    hat, star, all_paths = [], [], []
    for batch in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(dataloader)):
        i, (paths, images, target, skin_tone) = batch
        images = images.to(device)
        target = target.to(device)

        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(images)

        hat.append(output[:,1].detach().cpu().numpy())
        star.append(target.cpu().numpy())
        all_paths.append(paths)

    hat = np.concatenate(hat)
    star = np.concatenate(star)
    all_paths = np.concatenate(all_paths)
    threshold = model._ddi_threshold
    m_name = model._ddi_name
    m_web_path = model._ddi_web_path

    report = classification_report(star, (hat>threshold).astype(int), 
        target_names=["benign","malignant"])
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(star, hat, pos_label=1,
                                sample_weight=None,
                                drop_intermediate=True)
    auc_est = auc(fpr, tpr)

    if show_plot:
        _=plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 
            color="blue", linestyle="-", linewidth=2, 
            marker="o", markersize=2, 
            label=f"AUC={auc_est:.3f}")[0]
        plt.show()
        plt.close()

    eval_results = {'predicted_labels':hat, # predicted labels by model
                    'true_labels':star,     # true labels
                    'images':all_paths,     # image paths
                    'report':report,        # sklearn classification report
                    'ROC_AUC':auc_est,      # ROC-AUC
                    'threshold':threshold,  # >= threshold ==> malignant
                    'model':m_name,         # model name
                    'web_path':m_web_path,  # web link to download model
                    }

    return eval_results




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get arguments from command line
    args = get_args()
    # load model and download if necessary
    model = load_model(args.model, 
        save_dir=args.model_dir, download=not args.no_download)
    # load DDI dataset
    dataset = DDI_Dataset("DDI", transform=test_transform)
    # evaluate results on data
    eval_results = eval_model(model, dataset, 
        use_gpu=args.use_gpu, show_plot=args.plot)

    # save evaluation results in a .pkl file 
    if args.eval_dir:
        os.makedirs(args.eval_dir, exist_ok=True)
        eval_save_path = os.path.join(args.eval_dir, 
                                      f"{args.model}-evaluation.pkl")
        with open(eval_save_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(eval_results, f)

        # load results with:
        #with open(eval_save_path, 'rb') as f:
        #    results = pickle.load(f)

and here is the full trace back:
Exception has occurred: Exception
Please visit <https://stanfordaimi.azurewebsites.net/datasets/35866158-8196-48d8-87bf-50dca81df965> to download the DDI dataset.
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\ddi_dataset.py", line 37, in __init__
    raise Exception(f"Please visit <{DDI_Dataset._DDI_download_link}> to download the DDI dataset.")
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\eval_ddi.py", line 140, in <module>
    dataset = DDI_Dataset("DDI", transform=test_transform)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Exception: Please visit <https://stanfordaimi.azurewebsites.net/datasets/35866158-8196-48d8-87bf-50dca81df965> to download the DDI dataset.

I'm expecting to know why the problem happens and how to solve it.

Can you print the value of csv_path just before the exception ?

Hello there, can you please add the code that calls (instantiates) the DDI_Dataset? It'll help a lot.

@pac0 , the output is : DDI\ddi_metadata.csv

@LukeL, sorry , I don't know how to exactly calls (instantiates) the DDI_Dataset, but I tried to print the file path out by code (code: (1)print(os.path.abspath("ddi_dataset.py"))
,(2)print(os.path.abspath("ddi_metadata.csv")) ; output: (1)C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\ddi_dataset.py, (2)C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI\ddi_metadata.csv), will these help , or is there other actions I can do.

Well, it's not possible that you didn't instantiate the DDI_Dataset class, because code in function and classes don't execute on their own, so in order for an error to occur you must've called it somewhere. So essentially I'm asking you to provide the location where the error is first detected.

@LukeL, I edit my posts , and paste the code where calls the 'DDI_Dataset', does the information up there helps?

Could you please still [edit] to include the full traceback, using code formatting?

@triplee, I add it now, dose it help?

Yeah, it does help a lot. Thanks.

The file ddi_metadata.csv must be in the root folder, not in images

,sorry, I move the ddi_metadata.csv  to the root folder, but it still comes out the same error message.

Pass in r"C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset\DDI" instead of just "DDI", or make sure your working directory is C:\Users\User\OneDrive\desktop\CSproject\dataset; see also What exactly is current working directory?
